# Jquery find pattern in html and plain text

Tags: javascript, jquery

What is the best way using jQuery to turn this

```
<div class="some-name">
   <strong>8</strong>
   views
   <strong>2</strong>
   likes
</div>
```

into

```
<div class="some-name">
   <div class="wrap">
     <strong>8</strong>
     views
   </div>
   <div class="wrap">
     <strong>2</strong>
     likes
   </div>
</div>
```

?

I'm trying to wrap this pattern

```
<strong>some text</strong>
some text
```

in `<div class="wrap"></div>` but not sure which is the best way to group the `<strong`> and plain text pairs.

Note: I can't change the HTML before using Jquery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could filter through the `strong` elements, returning it and its sibling text node. Remove the text from the adjacent text node after it has been appended, and then wrap the returned elements:

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/h1ceqLL5/)

```
$('.some-name strong').filter(function () {
    $(this).append(this.nextSibling.nodeValue);
    this.nextSibling.nodeValue = '';
    return $(this);
}).wrap('<div class="wrap"></div>');
```

If you want the text node to be appended after the `strong` elements are wrapped:

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/no7jhemv/)

```
$('.some-name strong').wrap('<div class="wrap"></div>');
$('.some-name .wrap').each(function () {
    $(this).append(this.nextSibling.nodeValue);
    this.nextSibling.nodeValue = '';
});
```

Comment: Thank you! The code works but it also wraps everything in `<strong>`. Is it possible to leave the strong and plain text as is?